# Google Cloud vision API: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Hi I'm trying to use google's cloud vision API, specifically this example: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/label-tutorial#label_tutorial_1

I followed this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/getting-started#set_up_a_service_account for setting up a service account but when I run my code I get:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://vision.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1 returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

Can anybody help? I can't figure out what's going on, my code is 1:1 with the tutorials.

Answer (score 7):

You need to clean `~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json` from your computer. Then define your scope as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. Run your code again, it should ask you to re-authorize. Then run your code.

Comment: I couldn't find this file on my computer. I tried unhiding folders and still couldn't find the directory (i'm using a Mac). Any help on where to find it?

Comment: You need to delete token.json from your computer's local folder. Then rerun your program and reauthenticate (a new browser webpage will open).

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update & apt-get upgrade

pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

then initialized the gcloud sdk via ...

```
gcloud init
```

and voila it started working!

You can also try re-generating the credentials from the API manager

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`google.cloud` client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) for the Vision API instead.

To authenticate with the right scope, you'll need to generate a service account in the Cloud Console, and point to it from your code (or environment variables). See [the Vision auth section](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision-usage.html#authentication-and-configuration) for more info:

Get a service account from the [credentials manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) in the Cloud Console. Then point to your project and JSON credentials file in your environment:

```
$ export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT="your-project-id-here"
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/keyfile.json"
```

The demo you were trying to run (labeling an image) becomes:

```
>>> from google.cloud import vision
>>> client = vision.Client()
>>> image = client.image(source_uri='gs://my-storage-bucket/image.jpg')
>>> labels = image.detect_labels(limit=3)
>>> labels[0].description
'automobile'
>>> labels[0].score
0.9863683
```

(Code snippet taken from the [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision-usage.html#label-detection))