# python ) google spread sheet : update api does not work with 403

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm following the tutorial from this official link : https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python

I did execute 'quickstart.py' to authenticated.
After that, I ran 'quickstart.py' again and saw the data from 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0' as this tutorial gets.

I did change spreadsheet ID to my own id and make it to get the data from my spreadsheet by the method :`service.spreadsheets().values().get().execute()`

But my goal is to add data to my spreadsheet, so I used  the method 'update' as below:

```
rangeName = 'A2:D'
body['range'] = rangeName
body['majorDimension'] = 'ROWS'
body['values'] = ['test','test','test','test']
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName, body=body).execute()
print('result:'+str(result))
```

Then I got an error :

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/MY_SPREADSHEET_ID/values/A2%3AD?alt=json  returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

I don't know why this erorr occurs when trying to update my sheet and why this error doesn't occur when trying to get data from my sheet.(If it is cause by authentication, the method 'get' should cause it too!)

Thank you.

Comment: Please see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846446/google-cloud-vision-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes/36059258)

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for your link, but of course, I already found that post and it's not a 'gcloud' but 'google spreadsheet api' with python

Answer (score 6):

The quickstart.py example sets the scope to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

To update the spreadsheet you need to set the scope to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

You can do this by first deleting the existing authentication file in ~/.credentials (that is the location on a raspberry.). It will likely be called "sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json.

After you removed it you will need to re-authenticate, which should happen automatically when you re-run the script.

Comment: having exactly the same trouble as @LKM but if I delete the json in .credentials, and try to execute the same script I get `NameError: global name 'CLIENT_SECRET_FILE' is not defined`. And if I define the constants as in the example:
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'
I get `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: For any others as clueless as I: 1. Go to your google acct. API manager console and "RESET SECRET" 2. download the new json 3. rerun the script setting the constants: SCOPES = 'googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'; CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'your newly downloaded json file' APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'. Then, when you rerun the script, the flow function will open a browser and ask for login. Successful login will generate a new "sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json" file at ~/.credentials, and you're good to go. Thanks @Duppie. You pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Similar solution for me, except I had an previous "token.pickle" that I deleted.