# php with python google vision api giving error when loading in browser

Tags: php, python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have a problem when running the php script.

I am detecting faces through google vision api.

when running it in the terminal:

```
php name.php
```

I am seeing the output without having any problem.
But when I am running it from the web browser, I am having this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 139, in <module>
    main(args.input_image, args.output, args.max_results)
  File "test.py", line 115, in main
    faces = detect_face(image, max_results)
  File "test.py", line 84, in detect_face
    response = request.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 838, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

I tried to write in the terminal:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS= file.json
```

and then reopen the webpage in the browser, I still have the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: **Request had insufficient authentication scopes**?

Comment: @yivi yes, this is the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud vision API: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846446/google-cloud-vision-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes)

Comment: @GrahamPolley maybe it is a duplicate question, but I didn't find the answer in the ones you've tagged for me.
So can you help?

Comment: @Aline - I'm a little confused. Your error clearly shows that this is Python code. Where does the PHP come into this?

Comment: @GrahamPolley - Actually, I am using python code into php code. So I am facing the error when using the browser, not when compiling it from the terminal

Comment: @Aline - what do you mean you are _"using python code into php code_"?